# how to retrieve the value from database using find('first')

Tags: php, cakephp, find

I got 2 models called `locations` and `temperature_readings` working on localhost:

Components of locations: `id, name, high_threshold, low_threshold`.

Components of temperature_readings: `id, created, temperature, location_id`.

I try to do some conditions for my application and I need to get the values of `temperature`, `high_threshold`, and `low_threshold`.

I work in model `temperatureReadings.php` and I got the value of temperature by writing

```
$temperature = $this->data['TemperatureReading']['temperature'];
```

since I am working in model `temperatureReadings.php`.

The values `low_threshold` and `high_threshold` are in model `locations.php`.

So,

How can i get the values `low_threshold` and `high_threshold` using `find('first')` for model `temperatureReadings.php` ?

Comment: Are you using Containable? Whats the recursive level in the project and have you defined any associations between the two models?

Comment: What version of CakePHP are you using? Where in the model do you need access to the data of the other model? Could you add some code of the function, where you want to get access (in validation or a custom function to receive data)?